# Disable input until previous input is validated with bootstrap-validator

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, twitter-bootstrap, validation

I am using [bootstrap-validator](http://1000hz.github.io/bootstrap-validator/) and it works great for validation but I now need to disable an input until the previous input has been validated. I looked at the bootstrap-validator and I saw these [events](http://1000hz.github.io/bootstrap-validator/#validator-events) which look like they will help in this process, but I cannot figure out how to call them on an input id.

**HTML**

```
<form role="form" data-toggle="validator">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="login-name" placeholder="Your Name" data-error="Please provide a valid name" required>
      <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
    </div>
<div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="chosen-name" placeholder="Your Chosen Name" data-error="Please provide a valid name" required disabled>
      <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default action-btn">Submit</button>
  </form>
```

**JS**

```
//Bootstrap Validator
$('form').validator({
    // Trying to check if #login-name is valid, obviously not working!!!
    if(valid.#login-name){
        $('#chosen-name').prop('disabled', false);
    } else{
        $('#chosen-name').prop('disabled', true);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it uses the [Constraint Validation API](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-preview/constraints.html#the-constraint-validation-api) you can use

```
 //Bootstrap Validator
 $('form').validator().on('validated.bs.validator', function(e){
     var target = e.relatedTarget;
     if (target.id == 'login-name'){
         $('#chosen-name').prop('disabled', !target.checkValidity());
     }
 })
```

Demo at http://codepen.io/gpetrioli/pen/MaGJzL?editors=001

Comment: Spot on mate. Thanks heaps

Answer (score 2):

your js should be something like this:

```
 $('form')
.validator()
.on('valid.bs.validator', function (e) {
    if(e.relatedTarget.id==='login-name')
    {
       $('#chosen-name').prop('disabled', false);
    }
  })
.on('invalid.bs.validator', function (e) {
    if(e.relatedTarget.id==='login-name')
    {
       $('#chosen-name').prop('disabled', true);
    }
  })
```

Comment: Thanks mate, your solution looks like it should work, but it didn't. Strange